# How do I add additional headers to individual parts when using MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, multipart

It appears that my "old" way of constructing multipart bodies no longer works with versions of httpclient > 4.4.5.

Fair enough, so I looked around a bit and it appears that the "right" way to build multipart bodies now is with the `MultipartEntityBuilder`.

However, I don't see any way to provide additional headers (content-id, content-disposition, content-description, etc.) for the individual parts when using the `MultipartEntityBuilder`.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: In the EXPath HTTP Client, I decided to serialise the request entity content myself in case of multipart, for no support of pseudo headers. You might find the following useful: https://github.com/fgeorges/expath-http-client-java/blob/master/http-client-java/src/org/expath/httpclient/impl/MultipartRequestBody.java

Comment: I was doing something similar. It fails with 4.4.6 or later because of a narrower check on the content type header. But perhaps you're setting the content-type header directly and not calling some `.setContentType` method. I'll give that a try. AFAICT, the new httpmime library is solely focused on form submission.